# escape HtmlEntities in IE9 (using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, entities

I have this function:

```
function escapeHtml(input){
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.innerHTML = input;
    return d.innerText || d.text || d.textContent;
}
```

I have tested this function in FireFox and IE9 and got different results:

Firefox:

1. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&amp;")`   <==> `http://test.com&`
2. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&gt;")`    <==> `http://test.com>`
3. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&lt;")`    <==> `http://test.com<`
4. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&quot;")`  <==> `http://test.com"`
5. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&#39;")`   <==> `http://test.com'`
6. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&")`       <==> `http://test.com&`
7. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&abcdef")` <==> `http://test.com&abcdef`

IE 9

1. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&amp;")`    <==> `http://test.com&`
2. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&gt;")`     <==> `http://test.com>`
3. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&lt;")`     <==> `http://test.com<`
4. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&quot;")`   <==> `http://test.com"`
5. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&#39;")`    <==> `http://test.com'`
6. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&")`        <==> `http://test.com`
7. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&abcdef")`  <==> `http://test.com`

It means

- `escapeHtml` works correctly in Firefox in every case  1, 2, 3, 4, 5. 6, 7
- `escapeHtml` works incorrectly in IE9 of cases 6, 7 because it auto cut the string from `&` character.

  1. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&")`         <==> `http://test.com`
  2. `escapeHtml("http://test.com&abcdef")`   <==> `http://test.com`

How to change the function `escapeHtml` above to make it work correctly in IE9 like Firefox?

Comment: I am confused as to why you are decoding html in this way?  Try using `unescape()` which built into javascript.  It is much more efficient than creating a new DOM element and inserting and retrieving text to and from it each time you want to decode html.

Comment: Your function is called `escapeHtml`, but it appears to be trying to **un**-escape it, and the last example isn't even valid HTML.

Comment: @Ballbin — `unescape` is (a) Deprecated and (b) Handles form URL encoding, not HTML.